# Django user permissions on variable data

Tags: python, django

Ran into a problem that has me scratching my head, documentation hasn't really pulled me any luck so I figured I'd see if anyone else has been in this situation. So let's say I have a model (among others):

- Organization

That sort of acts like a psuedo-tenant. The thing is, users within my app may or may not have permissions to multiple organizations, some only 1, some this, some that. Point is, there's no clear structure on where permissions lay for each user. By default it should be none as it is now until manually granting, but instead of granting permissions to all or no organizations has anyone ran into a similar situation of being in need to control permissions in a granular/dynamic fashion? It is important to note that these 'organizations' are loaded dynamically via an API to an external product.

I realize this can be done by crafting my own sort of permissions system outside of Django but my main question is can this be done with conventional Django permissions or is this out of scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [object-level permission](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you could use something to help you with the object permissions, like [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). However, if it is for one model and it is something simple, consider also defining a custom permission in your organisation model:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):

    # your fields

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('my_shiny_permission', 'Some description for it'),)
```

And then in your views you can define the logic for it:

```
def my_view(request):

    if request.user.has_perm('my_app.my_shiny_permission'):
        # do something
```

More about custom permissions - [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions).